# how to use .toggle with jquery 2.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Function toggle() is deprecated and I don't know how to handle this problem. I tried some solutions but none of them worked for me. Here is my last try(still doesn't working);

```
<script>
$("#clickId").click(function(){
 var $block = $("#myDiv"),
     $this = $(this);
 $block.slideToggle(function(){
     $this.text($block.is(':display') ? 'hidden' : 'block');
 });
});
</script>


<a href="#" id="clickId" ><img src="/img/sample.png" alt="sample"/></a>
    <div id="myDiv" style="display: none !important">
```

**EDIT:** 
I changed below lines but still not working.

```
$this.text($block.is(':visible') ? 'false' : 'true');
<div id="myDiv" visible="false">
```

Comment: I think you want `:visible` instead of `:display`

Comment: @Pointy I tried visible but still not working. You mean visibility?

Comment: You have to use the value `none` to hide an element with style attribute `display`.

Comment: Well what exactly is going wrong? What is it that you want to happen, and what's happening instead? Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: @reporter well the code  as written is just dropping that as text into the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `slideToggle` is the duration, *then* the callback function:

http://jsfiddle.net/jgzucro8/

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#mydiv').slideToggle(0.5, function () {
        $('#btn').text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'visible' : 'hidden'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't I need to use <script></script> tag? I am new to js sorry?

Comment: If it's in an HTML document, yes. If it's in an external JS file, then it'll be included via the `<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>` tag. (`<script>` is part of HTML, not JavaScript, to be precise)

Comment: There is a display propery like div { display: block; }. So even I set visible="false" for #mydiv still I can see the div.

Comment: the `is(':visible')` and `<div visible="false">` are two different things. `visible="false"` is not valid HTML, and should be `style="display:none"` instead. To set the invalid `visible` property, use jQuery's `.prop()` method: http://api.jquery.com/prop/. Perhaps an explanation of what you want it to do would help.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript didn't identify the `$("#clickId")` and `$("#myDiv")` because the dom didn't load.
Use `$(document).ready()` or put your script after the dom (tag a and div)

Comment: I used $(document).ready() and also I put my script after the dom (tag a and div) but still doesn't working I mean when I click the image nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would just simplify your function a bit:

```
$("#clickId").click(function(){
   $("#myDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ssmmnfdd/1/